# Dynamic populate dropdown for Sweetalert2

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I am trying to populate a dropdown option for a SweetAlert alert by passing an array or string list from my MVC controller to view.

I can get the values to populate in the dropdown but when the text is selected it only returns the value such as 0 and will not return the text. Which is meaningless.

I have tried passing it in a two-dimensional array so I was setting the value and text but that didn't display right. I have also tried passing a directory but I was not able to get that to parse in my Jquery.

Sorry if this is something very obvious.

```
             var inputOptionsPromise = obj.Attatchments;
            alert(inputOptionsPromise);

        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Select Attatchment for Upload',
            input: 'select',
            inputOptions: inputOptionsPromise,
            inputPlaceholder: 'Select an attatchment',
            showCancelButton: true,
            inputValidator: (value) => {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
              if (value !== '') {
                resolve();
              } else {
                resolve('Select an attatchment');
              }
            });
          }
        }).then(function (result) {
          if (result.isConfirmed) {
// trying to get text value
              alert(result.value);
              alert(result.text);
              alert(result);

          }
        });


//Controller
string[,] array2D = new string[,] { { "text.pdf","text.pdf"}, { "test.txt", "test.txt" } };
                                //string[] array = new string[] { "text.pdf", "test.txt" };

return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Success = false, File = fileStream, Attatchments = array2D , ErrorMessage = "" }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```